# .htaccess rule for language detection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm stuck with some problem with .htaccess 
my simplified file server structure is the following:

```
/index.php
/signup.php
```

i need to work with virtual urls for handling the language switch:

```
www.mydomain.com/en/signup.php   
www.mydomain.com/de/signup.php
```

so my .htaccess should check if url contains /en/ or /de/ and translate it to eg. `/signup.php?language=de`

basically spoken, it should strip the language tag but keep the rest of the folder structure.

it should work on both my local xampp and on my live server.
any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 16):

What have you tried so far? Something like the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/(en|de)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L]
```

The meaning is rather obvious: take the second match (`$2`), that is what comes after the second slash in the URL, postpone a `?language=` after it, and then the first match (`$1`), that is, what's between the first two slashes - provided it's one of `en` or `de`.
If you wanna match anything (not only `en` or `de`) as language, then change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L]
```

**Please note**: the `?` in the first group will make the match stop at first slash, so that you won't rewrite eg.

```
/en/subdir/pippo.php
```

to

```
pippo.php?language=en/subdir
```

but rather to

```
subdir/pippo.php?language=en
```

In case of doubts, there is an [excellent documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) in the Apache website.

---

**Edit: default language**

To make all other requests (that is, URLs not starting with `/en/` or `/de/`) redirect to a default language (say `en`), first you have to know the language prefixes you want to recognize, and then use the following rules - below, I'm assuming there are three -3- languages, with codes `en`,`de` and `fr`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?language=en [L,QSA]
```

If you don't define the exact language set in the first `RewriteRule` (eg using my previous "any language" solution), language detection could fail on nested pages. It's important that the rules are in this order because the first one will match pages with the language code and then exit, whilst the second one will be applied only if the first does not match.

Comment: this looks pretty good :) how can i set my language default to EN? like if no language tag is defined -> redirect to mydomain.com/en/ ?

Comment: Since all these rules are flagged `[L]` (last rule checked), you could write a redirect to English after them all:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=$1 [L]`This rule MUST be last though.

Comment: @Fuxi do you want mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/en/ only, or all mydomain.com/stuff to go to mydomain.com/en/stuff? the second is a bit more complicated

Comment: hi paolo - yes i need the 2nd option :/

Comment: For me the second rule didnt work as expected. My css, js and images were not redirected correctly, althought I have had RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d statements before the rewrite rules. But it is working when I change the second rewrite rule to: RewriteRule ^(.+?)?/$  index.php?url=$1&lang=de [L,QSA]

Comment: How to do this when using a public folder?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor what do you mean? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @PaoloStefan i mean: if You use a folder anmeld `Public` and one named `App` like the framework Laravel, Then You need to set so the website "belive" that the `public` is the root. I did that and it kinda work if i type example.com/en/home but NOT if i type example.com/da/home. Then it fail and the URL miss up to end look like `example.com/public/home?lang=da`

Comment: @PaoloStefan Exactly what this guy are asking about http://stackoverflow.com/q/43159674/4691734.  I have that weird problem that the url mess up sometimes when you type another language in the url

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor you could use eg: `RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$  public/$2?language=$1 [L,QSA]` and then for the default language 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$  public/$1?language=en [L,QSA]`.This way you don't expose the `public/` dir in the URL.

Comment: this will mess up the query string if there are other variables:
`/en/signup.php?user=john` would be sent to `/signup.php?user=john?language=en`