# modrewrite/htaccess - force default language in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm struggling with a modrewrite/htaccess problem (using php).
i'm running a multi-language web which has urls like `www.mydomain.com/en/index.php`
"`en`" will translate as `&lang=en`

now i'm looking for a way to always force english as default language for ANY url- eg. if a user tries accessing an url like `www.mydomain.com/dashboard.php`, it should automatically translate to `www.mydomain.com/en/dashboard.php`

any ideas how to solve this?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect `/en/dashboard.php` if access? Or without redirect as if translated?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of languages your site supports:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|fr|es|de)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [R]
```

This will rewrite the url if it doesn't start with either `/en/`, `/fr/`, `/es/` or `/de/`.

Comment: looks nice, but when calling the root url (eg. mydomain.com) it causes an endless loop .. :/

Comment: That is not the cause of this rule. This rule will rewrite `mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/en/` and then this rule will not match anymore. Find out what rule is conflicting and alter that. In the worst case scenario change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1` to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ en/$1`.