# Language Rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, locale

Sigh...
I tried constructing some rewrite rules based on the following Stack Overflow questions:
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854831/modrewrite-htaccess-force-default-language-in-url)

My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|fr|es|de)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de)/(.*)$  $2?locale=$1 [L]
```

and I've tried all sorts of variations (including the exact answers given in the questions).

As it stands my URL is redirecting to:

```
/en/?locale=en
```

When I look at the root with what looks like an infinite redirect loop in Firefox ('The page isn't redirecting properly').

As you've probably guessed I want it to rewrite to /en/ on the root and for it to look like that in the browser. But I want the real url to be /?locale=en. There is an index.php there on the root. Maybe I need another rule to take that into account?

I don't know, I'm really tired and exasperated and .htaccess has always been my downfall. Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure there's no locale query string in your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !locale=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|fr|es|de)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]
```

Or you can try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!(en|fr|es|de)/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]
```