# Set language using htaccess URLrewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have for example two files in my root directory: **one.php** and **two.php**. I would like to reach them through these urls without having to actually have the physical directories en+de.

- mydomain.com/en/**one**
- mydomain.com/en/**two**
- mydomain.com/de/**one**
- mydomain.com/de/**two**

So the first directory would be "ignored" and just pass a GET variable with the language setting to the php-file, second directory is the php-file without extension.

This is what I'm using in my htaccess to loose the file extension so far:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**
This is quite useful: [.htaccess rule for language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection)
and this seems to pretty much do what I wanted:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

**ONE MORE ADDITIONAL QUESTION**
For mydomain.com/en/**one**/id45
If I wanna pass id45 as a variable to **one.php** what line in htaccess do I have to add?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are `one.php and two.php` in root or in `en/`, `de/` folders?

Comment: The files are in the root directory...I don't want to have the en+de folders physically I just need them in the URL for the language variable

Comment: @anubhava:Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Please post code examples properly formatted inside of your question, not in comments where they are pretty unreadable.

Comment: @CBroe: Done! Updated in Question.

Comment: @TomSenner you should post your update as an answer, since it is the answer.

Comment: @anubhava:Do you happen to know the solution to my additional question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash On

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/([^/]+)(?:/(.*)|)$ $2.php?lang=$1&var=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it causes a "500 internal server error" maybe my other code is wrong:   
`RewriteEngine on`<br/>  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  <br/>
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`  <br/>
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`  <br/>
`RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/([^/]+)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1&var=$3 [L,QSA,NC]`  <br/>
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=de [L,QSA]`

Comment: Your code works for 
mydomain.com/en/one/id45 but I'll get an 404 now for mydomain.com/en/one although the file one.php exists

Comment: Thanks almost perfect: Only mydomain.com/en/, mydomain.com/fr/ etc. is giving 404-error instead of using the index.php

Comment: But the directories DO NOT exist! mydomain.com/en/one -> will use one.php as a file so mydomain.com/en/ should use index.php in the same directory where one.php is. (Thanks for your great help btw)

Comment: why is there multiple RewriteRule for the language? and why do it load the CSS if I type example.com/en/home but not if I type example.com/de/home

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor: Please post a new question with all the details and I will try to answer it.