# Translating php webpage using gettext

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I am translating this webpage however I the translation will only work when I add the parameter after .php (e.g. http://localhost/fr/about.php?lang=fr_FR)

How can i make it work like (e.g. http://localhost/fr/about.php/?lang=fr_FR)

```
<?php

 /*
 * Template Name: Test */ 

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$locale_lang = "en_EN";
if (substr($url,0,3) == "/fr/") { $locale_lang = "fr_FR"; }
if (substr($url,0,3) == "/en/") { $locale_lang = "en_US"; }  
$lang = substr($locale_lang,0,2);
require_once("languages/lib/streams.php");
require_once("languages/lib/gettext.php");

$locale_file = new FileReader("languages/lib/$locale_lang/fr_FR.mo");
$locale_fetch = new gettext_reader($locale_file);

function _loc($text) {
    global $locale_fetch;
    return $locale_fetch->translate($text);
}

?>

<title><?php echo ("Title"); ?></title>
<h1><?php echo _loc("English Version"); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Brother, That page is only visible to you, because it is hosted on your server (which will only be visible to you) and not internet. Please add a global link.

Comment: Edit your .htaccess . That's exactly what you need. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection

Comment: @M.S.P are *you* serious?

Comment: Ofcourse @AmazingDreams

Comment: Why aren't you testing the `$_GET['lang']` variable?!