# Multiple language when using public folder in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, multiple-languages, public-folders

I have this **.htacces** file I like it a lot but how do I add multi language to it? so it understand that `localhost/en/` is not a file or folder. right now it use a public folder as the "root" so `localhost` = `public/`

Great if I then wanna do so I still use the public folder as a root but the first / / in the url is the language

Example: `localhost/en/` = link to the public folder and `localhost/it/` also link to the public folder

Example 2: `localhost/en/admin` link to `public/admin/`

> **PS:** the public/ is not suppose to been seen in the URL

This code do exactly what I wan't except the part with language.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]


ErrorDocument 401 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/errors.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/errors.php
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @starkeen year my English I bad... My problem is that I need it to ignore the first /en/ so it don't ask for a file or a folder

Comment: @starkeen in anyways it _need_ to the public folder as the root even when **/en/** isset. so if we example take **localhost/en/admin** it go to public/admin

Comment: Ok, try replacing the pattern of your first rule with this **^(?:en|it)/?(.*)$** .

Comment: @starkeen Sweeeet!! how to do so it can handle more than just *en* and *it*?

Comment: Just seperate the values by a pipe char **|** , example : **^(?:lang1|lang2|lang3|other)**

Comment: @starkeen are it possible to make it so you don't need to add the language in the `htaccess` every time you add a language? :)